# Usando o Google Maps API para determinada Longitude e Latitude

Tags: php, google-maps

Estou criando um site, quero que nele quando um usuário colocar em um input a longitude e latitude, o google maps retorna a localidade exata, já vi vários tutoriais falando sobre google maps api mas não consigo.

Aqui está o código que eu estou usando:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2ampkey=AIzaSyAaj8LTfKJ6tgN1ulSEUYsD9Xqs4wnurMs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="gmap" style="width: 100%"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function load() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("gmap"));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>), 13);
}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Mesmo não funcionando, é importante mostrar o código que já construiu para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Já leu a documentação do Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/) lá explica tudo e com exemplos

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com o código, como você mesmo falou que já tentou.

Comment: Se encontraste uma resposta a esta pergunta seria excelente colocares aqui, como resposta em baixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não chega a ser necessário realizar uma requisição ao servidor com a latitude e longitude. Você pode pegar os valores (com Javascript mesmo) da nova localização e somente atualizar o mapa por meio da função **`panTo()`**.

```js
(function() {

  /**
   * Inicializando o mapa.
   * DOCS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -23.6815315,
      lng: -46.8754965
    }
  });

  
  /**
   * Atualiza a localização com base nos valores inseridos nos inputs, quando o usuário
   * pressionar o botão 'buscar'.
   
   * Usando a função 'panTo' ao invés de 'setCenter' para fazer uma
   * transição mais amigável (animada) entre a localização antigaa e a nova.
   */
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value,
        lon = document.getElementById('lon').value;

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    map.panTo(point);

  }, false);

})();
```

```css
#map {
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>

<input id='lat' placeholder='Latitude'  />
<input id='lon' placeholder='Longitude' />
<button>Buscar</button>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Está dando um erro, eu até peguei o exemplo do docs, esta dando esse erro: Não foi possível exibir um elemento do Google Maps nesta página. Entre em contato com o administrador do site. Se você é o administrador do site, verifique o console do JavaScript ou a página a seguir para realizar a solução de problemas: http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors

Comment: O snippet rodou tranquilo, http://prntscr.com/a2vsbl

Comment: esse erro nao parece ter nada a ver com o código que postei ou com o google maps, onde esta a tentar integrar o código?

Comment: Eu acho que é o domínio.. Porque a google bloqueia os sites com subdominio grátis (.esy.es) eu estava usando este subdominio gratis (ou host grátis) pra testar como o site ficaria etc.. Agora vou comprar um domínio .com e vai dar tudo certo, eu acho.. Se der eu coloco sua pergunta como correta :)

Answer (score 1):

Visite o [Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) para exemplos completos.

Tem aqui um [exemplo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) que faz exatamente o que pede, para que funcione tem que substituir no URL `YOUR_API_KEY` pelo seu API KEY, se ainda não tem um pode criar [aqui](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE&reusekey=true).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

    </style>
    <style>
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu tentei usar esse código aqui, e deu isso: 

Não foi possível exibir um elemento do Google Maps nesta página. Entre em contato com o administrador do site. Se você é o administrador do site, verifique o console do JavaScript ou a página a seguir para realizar a solução de problemas: http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors

Comment: qual dos erros apareceu?

Comment: Simplismente não apareçeu o mapa! Ele deu um alert escrito oque eu citei, e mais nada.. Mas minha pergunta já foi respondida, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é esse o problema ou se já resolveu, mas tente fazer o que segue. Na consola de gestão de API, ative os seguintes APIs:

- Google Maps JavaScript API
- Google Maps Geocoding API

Comment: Já resolvi faz tempo, mas muito obrigado por reservar um tempinho seu para tentar me ajudar :)